# Разобрать многомерный массив

Tags: php, массивы, foreach

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 525
        [streetAddress] => г.Жуковка, ул.Карла Маркса, д.1
        [region_name] => Брянская область
        [city_name] => Жуковка
        [workhours] => пн-сб с 09:00 до 19:00, вс с 08:00 до 17:00
        [system_id] => 311142
        [phone] => 89123456789
        [extendedAddress] => Через дорогу от рынка, ТЦ «Пингвин», на 1-ом 
этаже
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 738
        [streetAddress] => г.Анапа, ул.Крымская, д.1
        [region_name] => Краснодарский край
        [city_name] => Анапа
        [workhours] => пн-сб с 09:00 до 19:00, вс с 09:00 до 18:00
        [system_id] => 310605
        [phone] => 89123456789
        [extendedAddress] => 
    )
```

Есть вот такой многомерный массив.
Как его разобрать чтобы получилось на выходе для каждого из вложенных массивов:

```
Адрес: г.Жуковка, ул.Карла Маркса, д.1
Область: Брянская область
Город: Жуковка
Рабочие часы: пн-сб с 09:00 до 19:00, вс с 08:00 до 17:00
и т.п.
```

как заменить ключи id, streetAddress и т.п. на свои?

```
foreach ($addressarray as $arr) {
      foreach($arr as $key => $value)
      {
         echo "$key = $value <br />";
      }
}
```

Comment: Что вызывает трудности?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Не получается составить верно цикл foreach
И как заменить ключи id, streetAddress и т.п. на свои?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Осторожно, бесплатный код

```
foreach ($addressarray as $address) {
    echo "
        Адрес: $address['streetAddress'] <br />
        Область: $address['region_name'] <br />
        Город:  $address['city_name'] <br />
        Рабочие часы: $address['workhours'] <br />
        и т.п <br />
    ";
}
```

Comment: про бесплатность понял) 
В общем, реализовал вот так: 

    foreach ($addressarray as $arr) {
            echo "
                Область: ".$arr['region_name']."<br />
                <!--Город: ".$arr['city_name']." <br /-->
                Адрес: ".$arr['streetAddress']." <br />
                Рабочие часы: ".$arr['workhours']." <br />
                Телефон: ".$arr['phone']." <br />";
                if ($arr['extendedAddress']) {
                    echo "Доп. инфо: ". $arr['extendedAddress']." <br />";
                }
                echo '<br />';
            }

Comment: А как можно отсортировать массив по 'region_name'? @AlexanderGrushko